# Loop for each file in directory but not throw error when no files present

Tags: files, zsh, wildcards

I want to load aliases based on the files in .profiles/ dir.

```
for profile in ~/.profiles/*; do
    for file in ~/.s1n7ax/$(basename $profile)/alias/*; do
        include "$file"
    done
done
```

However, when there are no any files inside `~/.s1n7ax/$(basename $profile)/alias/*` it throws an error.

```
/home/s1n7ax/.zshrc:117: no matches found: /home/s1n7ax/.s1n7ax/work/alias/*
```

I want to handle this gracefully without an error output to the sdt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `zsh` shell will treat unmatched filename globbing patterns as fatal.  If you are expecting a glob not to match anything, then you may use a globbing qualifier to make the pattern expand to *nothing* instead of failing:

```bash
for profile in ~/.profiles/*(.N); do
    for file in ~/.s1n7ax/$profile:t/alias/*(.N); do
        include $file
    done
done
```

Here, the trailing `N` in parentheses will make the pattern disappear completely if there is no matching filename, causing the corresponding loop to be skipped.  The dot is another qualifier that only selects regular files.  Would you additionally want to match *hidden* names, you should add `D` to the list of qualifiers.

The `N` qualifier has the same effect on the pattern as when setting the `nullglob` shell option in the `bash` shell, and `D` has the same effect as setting `dotglob`. The dot has no equivalence in `bash` other than iterating over the matching names and testing each with an `-f` test.

The `:t` at the end of `$profile` is short for "tail" and will give you the base name of the pathname in the variable.